# Making circular actions without inserting keyframes manually?

Tags: actions

I want to move my bone in a simple circular motion in the xz-plane in an action. I have tried to insert my keyframes manually to move in a circle, but it is always bumpy and I have a hard time making it loop. Is there a way to get it to loop in a circular motion in an action without "drawing" it with your own manual keyframes? I'm already bad at drawing circles. Or is there another way to go about it?
[image: Feet needs to move in a circle in an action]
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method for a primarily 2D context.

1. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the foot bone and go into edit mode of the armature. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>
2. Create a parent bone at the position, you wish to rotate the foot around. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> Bone.  <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the foot, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the parent, and parent them with an offset. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > Keep Offset.
   [image]
3. Select the child and in the Properties context, in the bone tab, in the Relations section, uncheck **Inherit Rotation**.
   [image]
4. Go into Pose Mode <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>. Select the parent, key the parent at a rotation of 0°, then at a rotation of 360° a few frame later. Locate the keys in the dopesheet and select them. Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Make Cyclic, to make the rotation action loop. Press <kbd>T</kbd> > linear, to transform it into a linear motion.
   [image]
5. Alternatively to the cyclic repetition, you could press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Linear Extrapolation.

Comment: Thanks for the great, easy to understand method. This should work perfectly. :D

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, but then I realized it because I was in quaternion mode so I changed it to XYZ Euler mode and that made all the difference. I have no idea what in the world those modes are, but it works now, so I'm happy. Thanks again. :)